# Autocomplete is not highlighting the selected value from dropdown and selecting duplicate values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator

My code for multiple select search dropdown from MUI

[image]

This is my API data after converting into desirable format (transformedSubLocationData) value

```
0: {label: 'Dialed Number 1', value: '0'}
1: {label: 'Dialed Number 2', value: '1'}
2: {label: 'Dialed Number 3', value: '2'}
3: {label: 'Dialed Number 4', value: '3'}
length: 4
            
                const [selectedNames, setSelectedNames] = useState([]);
                
                if(locationSubValue[formData.location.value] !== undefined){
                  // Transforming the sub location array into the required format
                  transformedSubLocationData = locationSubValue[formData.location.value].map((label, index) => ({
                    label,
                    value: index.toString()  // You can use the index as the value or any unique identifier
                  }));
                }
                
                <Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="fixed-tags-demo"
                value={selectedNames}
                onChange={(event, newValue) => {setSelectedNames([...newValue.filter((option) => option)]); changeHandleLocationErrorRemove(event)}}
                options={transformedSubLocationData}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
                renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
                  tagValue.map((option, index) => (
                    <Chip
                      label={option.label}
                      {...getTagProps({ index })}                      
                    />                    
                  ))                  
                }                
                style={{ width: 500 }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField {...params} label={formData.location.value} placeholder={formData.location.value} />                  
                )}                
            />
```

This is my code everything is same but in material UI site it is working but when the same code I copied to my JS file it stops working.
Please help as it is pending since long, didn't find any solution. Let me know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: I think your options value is not properly setting, can you show the full code or maybe share sandbox?

Comment: I have shared API response which I am adding in options value after converting into autocomplete array format.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your formData value is in TextField. But the issue is that you don't have to do the filer in `onChange`, the `newValue` has updated values as an array. You can just set `newValue` in `selectedNames`.

Also, you might get an warning for selected option check, to fix it i added a custom comparison method in `isOptionEqualToValue` prop.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, Chip, TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default App = () => {
  const [selectedNames, setSelectedNames] = useState([]);
  const transformedSubLocationData = [
    { label: "Dialed Number 1", value: "0" },
    { label: "Dialed Number 2", value: "1" },
    { label: "Dialed Number 3", value: "2" },
    { label: "Dialed Number 4", value: "3" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="fixed-tags-demo"
        value={selectedNames}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setSelectedNames(newValue);
        }}
        options={transformedSubLocationData}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
        renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
          tagValue.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip label={option.label} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
          ))
        }
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
          return option.value === value.value;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Edit: In case the `value` property in `transformedSubLocationData` is just for data creation purpose then you can skip it. You can just pass array of string to make it work. This eliminates adding `isOptionEqualToValue`.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, Chip, TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default App = () => {
  const [selectedNames, setSelectedNames] = useState([]);
  const transformedSubLocationData = [
    "Dialed Number 1",
    "Dialed Number 2",
    "Dialed Number 3",
    "Dialed Number 4",
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="fixed-tags-demo"
        value={selectedNames}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setSelectedNames(newValue);
        }}
        options={transformedSubLocationData}
        renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
          tagValue.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
          ))
        }
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I removed getOptionLabel, isOptionEqualToValue. In Chip, the label prop just takes option.

Comment: Your answer almost solved my problem, when I'm selecting values are getting selected in dropdown but I problem is when I come to update page and values are coming as selected in text field that is correct . But when I see dropdown then first value highlight is correct but second is wrong. Like if I choose "Dialed Number 1 and Dialed Number 4" then adding time value selection is fine, but when I'm coming to update page then highlight is wrong showing Dialed Number 1 and Dialed Number 2 as hihlight. If this is done then your answer will be up please help on this

Comment: This now seems to be a different issue than the one asked in the question. It's hard to debug without knowing how `transformedSubLocationData` is stored in your code. Are you storing transformedSubLocationData in useState? Please either update the question or raise a new question with the code to reproduce that issue. @NehaRaghuvanahi

Comment: transformedSubLocationData  I'm not storing this in useState, I'm transforming this for Autocomplete array format. It is just that I am not sure but something is there with this isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
          return option.value === value.value;
        }}

Comment: isOptionEqualToValue helps to highlight the correct option. In your case, your "value" is just the index of that object. Something in your code might be updating the data on render. Instead of option.value === value.value, you can try option.label === value.label. It's still hard to guess without any reproducible code of your update page.

Comment: I also added another example to eliminate the use of isOptionEqualToValue. See if that helps too. @NehaRaghuvanahi